# Cocos2d-Swift v3.x Sprite Builder : In iPad iPhone sd images are used. -ipad suffix ignored

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-swift

Code:

```
var bg = CCSprite(imageNamed:"Background.png")
```

Images used in Resource:

```
Background-hd.png
Background-ipad.png
Background-ipadhd.png
Background-iphone5hd.png
Background.png
```

In all device Background.png(320x480) used, other images are ignored. How to fix this ?

Retina display is not enabled...How to enable retina display in v3 ?

Here is [working sample code](https://app.box.com/s/jfrddgby4upj2c55w5thexybk79ljxyn) with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really advanced user of SpriteBuilder but have some concerns about your issue.

As you are using Sprite Builder for starting the project, it configures your CCFileUtils to distinguish different devices' resources by looking at folders, not prefixes. In your app delegate you can see this line:

```
[CCBReader configureCCFileUtils];
```

going into this method you can see that search mode for file utils is set to CCFileUtilsSearchModeDirectory

```
sharedFileUtils.searchMode = CCFileUtilsSearchModeDirectory;
```

So you need to use Publish folders and copy your Background image to each of them with the same name (Background.png), but with different resolution for each device.
[image]

You don't need to use image suffixes in SpriteBuilder at all.

Comment: not worked, even retina display is not enabled. Also there is no resource folder for iphone5, Is there any simple way to switch it to old way like -hd,-ipad ? any simple solution ?

Comment: thanks a lot for hints about CCFileUtilsSearchModeDirectory. I just replaced it with CCFileUtilsSearchModeSuffix and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. I had experience in cocos2d some time ago but I'm not experienced SpriteBuilder user, so sorry for such a short answer. Strange that it didn't work just by copying resources to Published-iOS folders, I have it working fine as expected. Here's a link to your sample project corrected with resources named Background.png and sorted to a corresponding devices' folders https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiy3tmgxtdyckf2/EntryMain.zip?dl=0

Comment: As for iphone 5 you need to name the folder as "resources-iphone5hd" just like another ones, and hope it works :) It seems that SpriteBuilder is not really updated to support iPhone 5, 6, 6+ and your way to use naming suffixes is a great idea. (cocos2d updates are much more frequent)

Answer (score 1):

Finally Updated Cocos2d and now -hd,-ipad files are used. Just updated one line

```
sharedFileUtils.searchMode = CCFileUtilsSearchModeSuffix
```